# Android scaling(Layout) problems

Tags: android, layout, scale

As you can understand from the title i have some problems with the scaling with what i am building at the moment. On my GalaxyS5 everything runs perfectly, however when i try to run it on a Samsung tablet with a bigger screen i get some problems.

Because i can't post pictures, here is a link that provides a visual description of my problem :
https://www.sendspace.com/file/83j0tp

**Update** : Since i have 10reputation posts, i can add the pictures.

**Samsung S5**

State 1

[image]

State 2

[image]

**SamsungTab (Tablet)**

State 1

[image]

State 2

[image]

This is my XML code :

I hope you guys can help me out.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loginImage2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/loginImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/loginImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/loginImage"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:id="@+id/textLoginmail" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="49.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Registreer"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textRegistreer"
        android:layout_weight="0.72" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textLogin"
        android:layout_weight="0.44"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="81dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/closeButton" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout_facebook">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/facebookImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_labels"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/overlay_for_terms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/textFacebook"
            android:layout_weight="0.90" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: follow  samsung s5 and tab has diffrent screen size http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: s5 take files from `hdpi` folder.. check ur tab folder it may take from `xhdpi` or `xxhdpi`

Comment: The pictures are picked from a server. Did you check the sendspace file? I don't think it is a problem of hdpi or mdpi, i think my code is not correct.

Comment: Don't know if it matters but I noticed that the weightSum defined in linearLayout6 is smaller than the sum of the weights of the subviews. Try leaving weightSum out or make it larger.

Comment: What you say is true uvo. one of the buttons become slightly larger then the other, however that doesn't solve my problem with the text that do stay fixed between the white marks but become large as hell... you cannot see it on the picture but even outside the button they are clickable. Thanks for your reaction though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I though it would be a better idea to tell the program on which screen which width it should use.

And thanks to Gaetan's tips it worked like a charm.
[Using different layout style on different screens (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212026/using-different-layout-style-on-different-screens-android)