# Using different layout style on different screens (Android)

Tags: android, layout, styles

I am having some problems with my layouts on one screen it's not well rescaled, some text pop- out of the button etc...

I thought of a fix for this but i need your help on this.

In my XML i have created :

```
<style name="styleforS5" parent="android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="samsungTablet" parent="android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">2.0</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Now my question is next : how can i write that if the input is a tablet it should use samsungTablet style and when its an s5 it should use stylefors5?

Thanks for you help,
Zak

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is - don't do it like that. It seems the answer requires an extensive instruction on the point and procedures to avoid approaching it like this. There's a system provided that largely takes the questioning out of it.

Comment: I have already tried many fixes. Didn't work, so this seems like the best option in my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the solution is to have only one style for both devices but define it in two specific folder based on smallest available width (See [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)) :

For **Smartphones (S5) : res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ImageButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1.0</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

And for **Tablets : res/values-sw600dp/styles.xml**

```
<style name="ImageButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">2.0</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

With these folder Android system will choose the "correct" style to use based on screen size.

Comment: I think this could indeed be a better fix. Gonna try it out right, but i dont have a standard values-sw600dp/styles directory, should i create it manually or?

Comment: Yes, you could create it manually or if you use Android Studio you can create a new Android resource directory and add a "Smallest Screen Width" qualifier